# Why would you ever change the application-host value in nexus.properties?

Tags: jetty, nexus

I have tried reading the Nexus documentation to find out what the application-host value in nexus.properties achieves.

Its default value is 0.0.0.0 and Nexus seems to work fine with this default value.

Under what circumstance would anyone want to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0

`0.0.0.0` when used as an address for how a server binds itself to the local machine's network interfaces means "bind to all IPv4 network interfaces".

If you have a machine that has ...

- 192.168.2.50 - physical network interface IPv4
- 127.0.0.1 - localhost / loopback
- 10.0.0.50 - virtual interface (container image)
- 2001:4860:4860::8888 - physical network interface IPv6

Then using `0.0.0.0` with port `8080` means that you now have 3 different ways that the server can answer a request.

- 192.168.2.50:8080
- 127.0.0.1:8080
- 10.0.0.50:8080
- (but not 2001:4860:4860::8888:8080)

If you wanted to be more selective you could use a specific address (instead of `0.0.0.0`) to have the server only bind to 1 network interface.

Example, if you used `192.168.2.50` in your nexus.properties then only that physical address will be bound to the server and listening for incoming connections.  You could not use `127.0.0.1:8080` to connect to that server (as there is nothing there listening).

Comment: In my case (as of 3.15.1-01, Win 10) I had to change the application-host field in this file to enable remote connections to the server, otherwise it would reject them.